# hyper-v 2012 forward all packets to a virtual NIC (promiscuous/hub mode)

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I have read from numerous sources that Hyper-V 2012 does not allow all packets from a physical NIC to be forwarded to a virtual machine. My situation is described in the pic below where I want all packets to be forwarded to the VM from a physical NIC. The issue is the hyper-v extensible switch filter blocks all non-broadcast traffic. How can I disable this filter and just have the packets passthrough?

I have tried creating a vm-switch extension following the instructions from: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Hyper-V-Extensible-Virtual-e4b31fbb#content However after I build the driver successfully I can't install it see receiving a confusing error: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Hyper-V-Extensible-Virtual-e4b31fbb/view/Discussions#content

I feel sure that there must be a simple solution to this that I am missing. Any advice appreciated!

Diagram - i.stack.imgur.com/cnMPu.png